# Creating ArrayList from Arrays

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to create 3 ArrayLists from some arrays like below:

```
([x,y])  ([x1,y1],[x2,y2],[x3,y3])  ([m1,n1],[m2,n2],[m3,n3],[m4,n4],[m5,n5])
```

Here is the code related to this part:

```
    public static ArrayList<Double[]>[] hexpos = (ArrayList<Double[]>[])new ArrayList[3];


      for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        hexpos[ i ] = new ArrayList<Double[]> ();
```

//====================initial arraylist1

```
     Double[] t = new Double[2]; 
     t[0]=x;
     t[1]=y;
     hexpos[0].add(t);
     System.out.println("xtest"+ hexpos[0].get(0)[0]);
     System.out.println("ytest"+ hexpos[0].get(0)[1]);
```

//======================== initial arraylist2

```
     int count=1;      
     t = new Double[2]; 
     t[0]=x;
     t[1]=y-(2*r);
     hexpos[count].add(t);

    t = new Double[2]; 
    t[0]=x+(3*s/2);
    t[1]=y-r;
    hexpos[count].add(t);

    t = new Double[2]; 
    t[0]=x+(3*s/2);
    t[1]=y+r;
    hexpos[count].add(t);
    count++;
```

//======================== initial arraylist3

```
    t = new Double[2]; 
    t[0]=x;
    t[1]=y-(4*r);
    hexpos[count].add(t);

    t = new Double[2]; 
    t[0]=x+(3*s/2);
    t[1]=y-(3*r);
    hexpos[count].add(t);


    t = new Double[2]; 
    t[0]=x+(3*s);
    t[1]=y-(2*r);
    hexpos[count].add(t);


    t = new Double[2]; 
    t[0]=x+(3*s);
    t[1]=y;
    hexpos[count].add(t);
```

I just print out the first arraylist as an example:
The output is:
xtest 400 ytest 400       xtest 400  ytest 400     xtest 400 ytest 400
The problem is that why it repeats 3times!!!

Comment: What is the size you have? what is the output that you expect? what is the output that you are getting?

Comment: What do you mean it "calls the first members 3 times"?  Are you sure?  Can you show us the context in which you're using it?

Comment: Thx for the kind reply, I have added more details of code and output to the post!

Comment: what is the value of `x`, `y`, `s` and `r` ?

Comment: put your whole code to analyse your problem ?

Comment: s=30; r=0.866*s;x=y=400;

Comment: @user3180204 put your code well format. where for loop start and where it is end?

Answer (score 3):

Try [Arrays.asList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29)

```
String arr1[] = {"111","poo","cfggg"};
String arr2[] = {"vfv","poc","cdegg"};

ArrayList<String> arrayList1 = new ArrayList<String>();
arrayList1.addAll(Arrays.asList(arr1));

ArrayList<String> arrayList2 = new ArrayList<String>();
arrayList2.addAll(Arrays.asList(arr2));

System.out.println(arrayList1);
System.out.println(arrayList2);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but it is possible to create them as array of arraylist!!?